# text is should be invisible

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

hello I have a animation I made it with Jquery

but I have a problem .text is visible while my info span coming and returning

I should keep that class in my .alert span

what am I trying to do is basicly I should make invisible .text class white alert box coming and returning

my code is here sorry for my bad english

wiro_notify

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("body").html(
    '<span class="alert" id="success"><i class="fal fa-check icon"></i><span class="text"></span></span>'
  );
  $(".text").text("Successful");
  var width = String($(".text").width() + 105) + "px";
  var min = $(".text").width() + 105;
  $("#success").animate({ bottom: "25%" }, 1000);
  if (min < 200) {
    $("#success").animate({ width: "200px" }, 1000);
    $(".text").css("margin-left", "10px");
  } else {
    $("#success").animate({ width: width, "margin-left": "5px" }, 1000);
    $(".text").css("margin-left", "7px");
  }
  $("#success").delay(4000).animate({ width: "80px" }, 1000);
  $("#success").animate({ bottom: "0", "min-width": "80px" }, 1000);
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  color: white;
}

body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 120vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: black;
}

.alert {
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  border-radius: 40px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
}

.icon {
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  border-radius: 40px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 50px;
  padding-top: 15px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.fa-check {
  background-color: rgb(3, 182, 3);
}

#success {
  background-color: rgb(0, 153, 0);
}

.text {
  margin-left: 7px;
  font-size: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 32%;
  white-space: nowrap;
  font-family: "Source Sans Pro", sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" />
<link
  href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Source+Sans+Pro&display=swap"
  rel="stylesheet"
/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body></body>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Here you go...**

Add this to your JS:

```
  $(".text").css("color", "transparent")
  setTimeout(function() {
    $(".text").css("color", "white")
    setTimeout(function() {
      $(".text").css("color", "transparent")
    }, 5000);
  }, 1000);
```

You set the color of `.text` to transparent. With the `setTimeout` you change the color from transparent to white after 1000 ms (i.e. right after the green element comes up). Then use the `setTimeout` again and change the color back to transparent after 5000 ms (i.e. right before the green element starts to go down).

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $("body").html("<span class=\"alert\" id=\"success\"><i class=\"fal fa-check icon\"></i><span class=\"text\"></span></span>")
  $(".text").text("Successful")

  var width = String($(".text").width() + 105) + "px"
  var min = ($(".text").width() + 105)

  $("#success").animate({
    "bottom": "25%"
  }, 1000)
  if (min < 200) {
    $("#success").animate({
      "width": "200px"
    }, 1000);
    $(".text").css("margin-left", "10px");
  } else {
    $("#success").animate({
      "width": width,
      "margin-left": "5px"
    }, 1000)
    $(".text").css("margin-left", "7px")
  }

  $("#success").delay(4000).animate({
    "width": "80px"
  }, 1000)
  $("#success").animate({
    "bottom": "0",
    "min-width": "80px"
  }, 1000)

  $(".text").css("color", "transparent")
  setTimeout(function() {
    $(".text").css("color", "white")
    setTimeout(function() {
      $(".text").css("color", "transparent")
    }, 5000);
  }, 1000);
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  color: white;
}

body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 120vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: black;
}

.alert {
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  border-radius: 40px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
}

.icon {
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  border-radius: 40px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 50px;
  padding-top: 15px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.fa-check {
  background-color: rgb(3, 182, 3);
}

#success {
  background-color: rgb(0, 153, 0);
}

.text {
  margin-left: 7px;
  font-size: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 32%;
  white-space: nowrap;
  font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en'>

<head>
  <meta charset='UTF-8'>
  <meta http-equiv='X-UA-Compatible' content='IE=edge'>
  <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0'>
  <title>Document</title>
  <link href='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css' rel='stylesheet' integrity='sha384-BmbxuPwQa2lc/FVzBcNJ7UAyJxM6wuqIj61tLrc4wSX0szH/Ev+nYRRuWlolflfl' crossorigin='anonymous'>
  <script src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js'></script>
  <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='style.css'>
  <script src='javascript.js'></script>
</head>

<body>



</body>

</html>
```